# Want to replace value in one column from another column based on specific condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace ABC with the value of next column for that particular row. If ABC lies in last column then value should be from previous column. If nan is present then it should be not be replaced by any other value. In-fact, we have to do this operation till nan if present.

Dataframe is as given below:

```
    C1  C2  C3  ……. C47 C48 C49 C50
1   0   ABC 15  ……. 29  ABC 90  50
2   ABC ABC 7   ……. 26  10  ABC 30
3   ABC ABC ABC ……. ABC ABC ABC ABC
4   6   20  32  ……. 18  44  ABC ABC
5   2   ABC 24  ……. 16  27  29  ABC
6   23  4   49  ……. 11  52  33  9
7   17  12  2   ……. ABC 31  nan nan
8   ABC nan nan ……. nan nan nan nan
9   34  36  2   ……. 19  ABC nan nan
```

output should be:

```
    C1  C2  C3  ……. C47 C48 C49 C50
1   0   15  15  ……. 29  90  90  50
2   7   7   7   ……. 26  10  30  30
3   0   0   0   ……. 0   0   0   0
4   6   20  32  ……. 18  44  44  44
5   2   24  24  ……. 16  27  29  29
6   23  4   49  ……. 11  52  33  9
7   17  12  2   ……. 31  31  nan nan
8   0   nan nan ……. nan nan nan nan
9   34  36  2   ……. 19  19  nan nan
```

Please note ABC will be 0 only when there is no value present in rest of the columns for that particular row.

Comment: why in the 4th row ABC is assigned 44 and not 0? absurd logic !! you said you want the next column value!

Comment: on the 5th row you get ABC as 24 and not 2. how do you decide to take value for ABC from which column? right or left ?

Comment: @KMM when dealing with logical operations it is very important (necessary) to have well defined and consistent rules.  Your description of what you want to happen does not match the provided example, which makes it impossible for us to help (i.e. we don't know what the logic of what you are trying to accomplish).  Please clean up your example so we can better assist.

Comment: @Nihal initially you have to pick the value from right and if value is not available on the right, you can pick it from left as shown in 5th row. I think this should also solve the query regarding 4th row. Thanks.

Comment: @tnknepp I know rules are not consistent but this is the requirement to do analysis. Let me explain it more deeply. Once nan is started to come there will be no other value or ABC present in rest of the columns. Then as i explained to Nihal, initially value should be picked from right side column only and if value is not available on right side(if ABC is present in let's say column 36 to column 50)   then only value will be assigned from left column. Scenarios where all the columns contains only ABC, it will be replaced by 0.

Comment: @tnknepp In other scenario, where let's say initial 10 columns contains ABC and rest of the columns contains nan then ABC will replaced by 0 and nan will remain as it is. Hope i am able to explain. thanks for interest.